# Is there any way to merge accounts which are unregistered?

Tags: discussion

A user has asked a lot of questions here without registering:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21837/2322
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/22228/2322
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21674/2322
- [If I love my job (and company), but my role has been stripped of responsibilities, what will I gain from staying?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21546/2322)
- [How can I explain in an interview that I quit due to being passed over for a promotion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21471/2322)
- [How to react when I am demoted for reasons not related to my performance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21427/2322)

There are quite a few unregistered accounts I can see (there may be more questions/accounts):

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/18503/antarcticgorillas
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/18280/antarcticgorillas
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/18154/antarcticgorillas
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/17960/antarcticgorillas

How should this be handled?

Comment: see also: [One user seem to be posting from (at least) four accounts, please help to sort it out](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/one-user-seem-to-be-posting-from-at-least-four-accounts-please-help-to-sort-i). This is becoming a bit too cumbersome; I wouldn't be surprised if we eventually request for requiring registration for askers, like it was done at Stack Overflow and at Programmers

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening in increasing frequency. To get the accounts merged, the user will need to request it.  I left the following comment under the most recent post from this person:

> Hey AntarcticGorilla, the creation of multiple questions does lead to some problems, so if you're planning to continue to participate, I encourage you to register and then [see these instructions on how to request an account merge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). When contacting the team, you may want to reference [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/is-there-any-way-to-merge-accounts-which-are-unregistered) as one of our users was kind enough to put together links to all your profiles. :)  Good luck!

Just in case this person loses access to the most recent account, please feel free to reuse this or a variation of this comment if another question pops up from yet another new account.

Comment: for the reference, here is an example (status-completed) request to establish registration requirement for askers, along with example justification: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users (our justification, if any, would likely differ, it's only an example)